# Clustering business terms in weka

Tags: cluster-computing, weka, taxonomy

I am trying to use weka to cluster business terms. I have a file with 12,000 term names and definitions and am looking to group them into broader subject areas as a way to seed a taxonomy. I am experimenting with different clusterers but not getting any interesting results. Typically it creates one cluster or just seems to die without showing output. Any advice for how to get off the ground for a newbie? I have used weka before, but mostly for classification. My efforts to research online haven't yielded much useful info.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What clusterers have you used so far and what were the results of each?  What kind of 'interesting' results are you looking for in your experiments?  Have you reserved enough memory for Weka to handle the size of your data?

Comment: I am looking to find patterns in the names and definitions that will help group these terms into higher level subject areas. I did adjust my heap size to to 3072m. When I ran EM, it created two clusters - one with the empty definitions (5%) and the other with everything else. Ran hierarchical and it says building the training set but then just stops with no message. Ran Cobweb and it churned  that first step for an hour. k means just put 100% into 1 cluster and 0 into another. Clearly, I am missing a major step in my input. Thanks!!

Comment: I don't believe that you are necessarily missing a step, but perhaps throwing more data into the clustering tool than can be handled.  It's possible that you may need to reduce the dimensionality of your data in order to feed them into your clustering algorithm.  Do you know how many attributes/words are in your dataset?

Comment: 12,000 terms (many having multiple words) and their definitions. Thought that more data would be better but maybe I should cut the definitions?

Comment: @user1038067 how you did to solve your problem, i have the same